# Mercurial command to combine hg pull; hg up

Tags: mercurial, pull

How can I combine the Mercurial commands `hg pull` and `hg update` into one?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Obviously, `hg pull -u` is the answer here.

However, there's a caveat that deserves mentioning: `hg pull -u` is not exactly equivalent to `hg pull` && `hg update`. This is briefly mentioned in the documentation, but it can be surprising if you first run into it; if there's nothing to pull (e.g. no new changesets came in), then `hg pull -u` doesn't update. This can be slightly confusing if you weren't on a head before issuing the command.

Comment: Does TortoiseHg have an equivalent?

Comment: Unfortunately, since `hg pull -u` does exactly what djc describes, I have had to resort to the `hg pull && hg update` as the only way to get this to work like "git pull", thanks for the tip.

Comment: @User - In TortoiseHg you can go to 'Settings' > 'Sync' > 'After Pull Operation' and select "update" from the drop down to do an automatic update after a pull.  The hints at the bottom of the page say that it "equates" to `pull --update`.

Answer (score 4):

type `hg help pull` and you will see the `-u` switch

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
hg pull -u
```

Read the documentation for more options.

Answer (score 1):

The `hg fetch` extension will do the same once enabled.  However, it has fallen out of favor and is noted as an "unloved feature" by the Mercurial team.