# Mercurial equivalent of "git pull --rebase"

Tags: git, mercurial, git-rebase

Is there a Mercurial equivalent of `git pull --rebase`?

Comment: For followers looking for "the mercurial equivalent of `git pull`" (the normal merge way -- non rebase) it's `hg pull && hg update` see http://stackoverflow.com/a/15244773/32453

Comment: Or a little shorter: `hg pull --update`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try `hg pull --rebase`.  Mecurial's pull is git's fetch, and git's fetch is mercurial's pull, but when you're rebasing you're updating the working dir either way, so `hg pull --rebase` is your guy.

NOTE: Because `rebase` alters history, it's disabled by default. You can turn it on (no need to download, you already have it)  by adding the following in the configuration file:

```
[extensions]
rebase =
```

([more info](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RebaseExtension))