# Is there a term in Mercurial for a pull followed by an update?

Tags: mercurial

In git this would be just a pull, but in Mercurial pull and update are separate operations. I hate having to say "do a pull and update" when telling someone how to grab the latest code, because it's so wordy. Is there a word for "pull and update" I can substitute this with?

(different from alleged "duplicate" question because I'm asking about terminology, not actual commands)

Comment: I would like the slang to be **stay fresh** ;)

Comment: Note that there used to be a command spelled `hg fetch` that was short for pull-then-update. This is particularly nasty since then `git fetch` = `hg pull` while `git pull` = `hg fetch`! :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mercurial command to combine hg pull; hg up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15241394/mercurial-command-to-combine-hg-pull-hg-up)

Comment: What about "pulldate"? ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can tell them to do `hg pull --update` or `hg pull -u`. You could also make a shell alias that does that and call it something.

Comment: This is the best answer. You can also add --rebase.

Comment: Given the problematic aspects of `fetch`, a reasonable word to use informally (and  perhaps as a user-defined alias for `hg pull -u`) would be "resync".